# sqlite3_finalize on below statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have the below code, i keep getting database locks and thing its because sqlite3_finalize is not being called. However I'm un sure how to do this with my code.

```
-(BOOL) saveLogin:(NSString*)access_token expires_in:(NSString*)expires_in refresh_token:(NSString*)refresh_token token_type:(NSString*)token_type saved:(NSString*)saved;{
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK){
            NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO login (access_token,expires_in, refresh_token, token_type, saved) values (\"%@\",\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",access_token,expires_in, refresh_token, token_type, saved];
            const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE){
                sqlite3_close(database);
                return YES;
            }else {
                NSLog(@"Error %s while preparing statement", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                sqlite3_close(database);
                return NO;
            }
        }
        sqlite3_close(database);
        return NO;
    }
```

Comment: Start by removing all the `return` statements, apart from one.

Comment: You have to finalize the statement on both sides of your if-branch.  The only case where you wouldn't is if `prepare` failed, but you're not actually testing the returned value of `sqlite3_prepare_v2` to see if it worked or not.  I agree your multiple returns are unnecessarily complicating things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is unnecessarily complex.

You should reorganize the code so that all cleanups are done in a single place:

```
BOOL result = NO;
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            result = YES;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error executing statement: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error preparing statement: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
} else {
    // open failed
}
return result;
```

Please note that reopening the database for every access is needless effort; you should open it only once when your app starts.